# Debian 10 (buster) sshd will not run correctly

Tags: debian, sshd

I am experiencing problems with sshd on Debian 10 (buster).
When I try to access from remote, the connection is automatically refused, and when I try to restart ssh.service, the process remains  blocked until a timeout error is shown:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
Restarting ssh (via systemctl): ssh.serviceJob for ssh.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

The only way I have to log in remotely is to reinstall `openssh-server` (wt.. ? yes)

The ssh.service unit is the following (the default one)

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify
RuntimeDirectory=sshd
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

The `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is also the following one:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.103 2018/04/09 20:41:22 tj Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
#Subsystem  sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

What's happening here ?

**UPDATE #1:**

This is the `journalctl -xe` output

```
Feb 14 08:23:04 arm systemd[1]: systemd-fsckd.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The unit systemd-fsckd.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Feb 14 08:23:05 arm systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.service: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The unit apt-daily-upgrade.service has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Feb 14 08:23:05 arm systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
-- Subject: A start job for unit apt-daily-upgrade.service has finished successf
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit apt-daily-upgrade.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 247.
Feb 14 08:23:46 arm sudo[3263]: pam_unix(sudo:auth): authentication failure; log
Feb 14 08:23:50 arm sudo[3263]:      szx : TTY=ttyPS0 ; PWD=/home/szx ; USER=roo
Feb 14 08:23:50 arm sudo[3263]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user
lines 1141-1163/1163 (END)
```

and this is the output of `systemctl status ssh`:

```
* ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enab
   Active: activating (start-pre) since Fri 2020-02-14 08:25:35 UTC; 27s ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
Cntrl PID: 3268 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           `-3268 /usr/sbin/sshd -t

Feb 14 08:25:35 arm systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

**UPDATE #2:**

I also noticed that sshd remains executes with `-t` option:

```
ps aux | grep sshd
root      3126  0.0  0.2  11828  4936 ?        Ss   08:39   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -t
szx       3156  0.0  0.0   3472  1732 ttyPS0   S+   08:39   0:00 grep sshd
```

I think this is consecuence of the `ExecStart` or `PreExecReload` directives in `ssh.service`...

**UPDATE #3:**

If I run `dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server` I can login remotely, but only until the end of the server session. So I should run `dpkg-reconfigure` after every boot...

Comment: Need more info:
Please try to restart sshd and then post the output of `journalctl -xe`

Comment: I updated as per your request.

Comment: Aren't you being hit by [#912087](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=912087) (openssh-server: Slow startup after the upgrade to 7.9p1)? Check when you get the `random: crng init done` log message.

Comment: I don't know. I installed Debian 9 instead of 10 which does not suffer from this problem. This is not a solution to this problem but doesn't make me waste valuable time in ssh issues.